# Create function in MYSQL with varchar and if: why doesn't it compile?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting mad since 30 minutes. The error isn't clear, I've looked carefully the documentation, I've tried to add and remove ";" and other tokens. Why it doesn't compile?

```
CREATE FUNCTION NormalizzaAutori(autore VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
BEGIN
  IF autore = 'a1'
 THEN 
  RETURN ('a');
 ELSE 
    RETURN (autore);
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION NormalizzaAutori(autore VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
BEGIN
  IF autore = 'a1'
 THEN 
  RETURN ('a');
 ELSE 
    RETURN (autore);
  END IF;
END;
```

As your stored custom function used multiple MySQL lines separated with semicon (`;`), you need to (re)define a new MySQL line separator with `DELIMITER` to get it working.

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e2z2da6DK6RnG871t6wabt/2)

But when you need to run more MySQL statements after this one to you need to use

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION NormalizzaAutori(autore VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
BEGIN
  IF autore = 'a1'
 THEN 
  RETURN ('a');
 ELSE 
    RETURN (autore);
  END IF;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

instead to reset the `DELIMITER` back to default, see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e2z2da6DK6RnG871t6wabt/7)

But in this case i would phrase the MySQL code myself as

```
CREATE FUNCTION NormalizzaAutori(autore VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
RETURN
 CASE 
  WHEN  autore = 'a1'      
  THEN 'a'
  ELSE autore                                          
 END
```

instead to simplify to a single statement as `BEGIN` and `END` is totally optional to use, also the `RETURN` and condition checking can be done in one go. see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e2z2da6DK6RnG871t6wabt/3)

The

```
 CASE 
  WHEN  autore = 'a1'      
  THEN 'a'
  ELSE autore                                          
 END
```

could also be replaced with

```
 IF(autore = 'a1'
    , 'a'
    , autore
 )
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e2z2da6DK6RnG871t6wabt/5)